# How to set mail-user-agent to mu4e-user-agent

Tags: org-mode, mu4e, org-mime, htmlize

Pressing `, m` in an org buffer does `org-mime-org-buffer-htmlize` and opens the
htmlized message in *message-mode* **but** I want it in *mu4e-compose-mode*.

How can I have this message opened in mu4e in order to have the sent mail stored
in my /SENT folder and benefit from mail address autocompletion?

Setting `mail-user-agent` in `.spacemacs` makes no difference:

```
(setq
mail-user-agent 'mu4e-user-agent
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the source code of `org-mime-org-buffer-htmlize`, it seems that `message-mode` is the hard-coded mail composition mode used by the function.

I am a user of neither Spacemacs nor mu4e, but you *might* get away with using advice (untested):

```el
(advice-add 'org-mime-org-buffer-htmlize :after-while
            'mu4e-compose-mode)
```

However, this seems like the kind of thing where a feature request to the maintainers would be more appropriate in the long run.